# UV unwrap and apply to similar

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm new to Blender, and I did some modelling, liked what I had...however I'd forgotten entirely about UV unwrapping.  I'm hoping to use this in UE4.

[image]

It's made out of identical parts, however none of them are UV unwrapped.  Is there any way to unwrap one, and then copy that map to all the others.  Or is it just worth starting again and doing it properly in the first place?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If using in game engine I'd suggest create low poly object which will be just huge cylinder overlapping those bricks, unwrap *that* mesh and bake maps - bump, normal, cavity etc. Nevertheless you can tranfer uv maps with Make Links operator but if meshes are the same.

Comment: Is that one single mesh or multiple objects? If those are multiple object instances then UVs are kept in sync automatically. If those are multiple objects but not clones you can easily make them clones of each other. If that is one single mesh object then as Mr Zak suggested you are probably better off breaking it appart into components then baking it to a low poly version.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I think I'll give baking to a low poly mesh a go.  Appreciate it.